# Adding Posts To A Collection with Join Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a 'Collections' model to group Posts so that any user can add any Post they like to any Collection they've created.  The Posts will have already been created by a different user.  We are just letting other users group these posts in their own Collections. Basically like bookmarking.

What is the cleanest, and most Rails-ey-way of doing this?

I've created the model and run through the migration and what not.  Also I've already created proper views for Collection.

`rails g model Collection title:string user_id:integer`

**collections_controller.rb**

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @collections = current_user.collections.all
end

def show 
    @collection = Collection.all
end

def new 
    @collection = Collection.new
end 

def create 
    @collection = current_user.collections.build(collection_params)
    if @collection.save
        redirect_to @collection, notice: 'saved'
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end

end

def update

end


private
  def collection_params
    params.require(:collection).permit(:title)
end


end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts

  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_many :collections
```

It seems like `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations are not correct?  Should I be creating another model to act as an intermediary to then use 
`has_many :collections :through :collectionList`?

If my association is wrong, can you explain what I need to change to make this work?

Also the next part in this is since this is not being created when the Post or Collection is created, I'm not sure the best way to handle this in the view.  What is the best way to handle this, keeping my view/controller as clean as possible?  I just want to be able to have a button on the Post#Show page that when clicked, allows users to add that post to a Collection of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you should use or `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` association. The second one is recommended, because it allows more flexibility. So now you should:

1. Create new model PostsCollections

   `rails g model PostsCollections post_id:integer collection_id:integer`

   and migrate it
2. Set correct model associations:

Something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_collections
  has_many :categories, through: :posts_collections
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_collections
  has_many :posts, through: :posts_collections
end

class PostsCollections < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

Then you'll be able to use

```
@collection.first.posts << @post
```

And it will add @post to @collection's posts

3. To add a post to a collection from view

Add a new route to your routes.rb, something like:

```
resources :collections do # you should have this part already
  post :add_post, on: :member
end
```

In your Collections controller add:

```
def add_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
  @collection.posts << @post
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

As for views, you'll have to create a form to show a collection select and button to add it. That form should make POST method request to add_post_collection_path(@collection) with :post_id parameter.

You can read more explanations of how rails associations work [in Michael Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-relationship_user_associations), because that subject is very wide, and can't be explained with short answer.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more, with more code samples on how I actually create this in the view?  I'm still trying to understand Join Models